# Ordenar uma lista <ul> pelo atributo "value"do <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, classificação

Fala pessoal, tudo bem? 
Então, estou com um problema...

Possuo um botão "ordenar por", no caso, de maior preço e menor preço.
O que eu preciso fazer, é ordenar os elementos de uma lista `<li>` pelo seu atributo `value`. Por exemplo: `<li value="200">`. Vale lembrar que o que a lista contém não pode influenciar na ordenação. `<li value="200">Não importa o que há aqui</li>`.
Tenho uma demo funcionando, mas ela transforma meu attr('value') em texto.. Não estou sabendo o que fazer...

```
<ul id="list">
    <li value="20">doesnmatter1</li>
    <li value="10">doesntmatter2</li>
    <li value="5">doesntmatter3</li>
    <li value="30">doesntmatter4</li>
    <li value="519">doesntmatter5</li>
</ul>

<button id="ordena-menor">Sort</button>
<button id="ordena-maior">Sort</button>



$(function() {
            $('#ordena-menor').click(function() {
                var liContents = [];
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    liContents.push(parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10));
                });
                liContents.sort(numOrdDesc);
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    $(this).text(liContents.pop());
                });
            });

            $('#ordena-maior').click(function() {
                var liContents = [];
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    liContents.push(parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10));
                });
                liContents.sort(numOrdCres);
                $('ul li').each(function() {
                    $(this).text(liContents.pop());
                });
            });
        });

        function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
            return (b - a);
        }

        function numOrdCres(a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        }
```

Agradeço desde já, um forte abraço amigos!

-> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s10d14vh/) <-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('#ordena-menor').click(function() {
  $("#list li").sort(numOrdDesc).appendTo('#list');
});

$('#ordena-maior').click(function() {
  $("#list li").sort(numOrdCres).appendTo('#list');
});


function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
  return ($(b).val()) < ($(a).val()) ? 1 : -1;
}

function numOrdCres(a, b) {
  return ($(b).val()) > ($(a).val()) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="list">
  <li value="20">doesnmatter1</li>
  <li value="10">doesntmatter2</li>
  <li value="5">doesntmatter3</li>
  <li value="30">doesntmatter4</li>
  <li value="519">doesntmatter5</li>
</ul>

<button id="ordena-menor">Sort</button>
<button id="ordena-maior">Sort</button>
```